# Can I use open_basedir or is it deprecated?

Tags: php

Excuse me in advance for the strange question :-)

I'm using the last stable php version, and I want to "jail" php scripts. (I tried to chroot, but it is boring.

I would like to use open_basedir directive on php.ini, but I don't know with it's deprecated or not. I searched on Google and 99% times the page redirect to http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php (DEPRECATED).

So my question is, Can I use this directive or not? is it sure?

Thank you really much

Answer (score 3):

PHP Safe Mode is deprecated. open_basedir is **NOT** deprecated. There is a lot of overlap between what these constructs address.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir, so this feature doesn't rely on safe_mode.

> This directive is NOT affected by
>   whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.

Answer (score 0):

> http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

There is nothing about this directive being deprecated. But restricting directory access with this does not prevent other people to see someone else code (ex using `shell_exec` and `cat`). So I would suggest to disable all functions that allows external program execution or use patch for php to allow only trusted executables from specified directory http://www.kyberdigi.cz/projects/execdir/english.html

On a side note, jail chroot is not boring, it's exciting considering how much work it requires to get all running ;)

Comment: yes is not boring but i have to copy all the directories...and if I have 200 website on the same server it will waste a lot of space...Maybe symbolic link?